# Equation involving modulus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

Solve the equation ,

$|x+1| + |x-2| = |2x-1|$

This was the solution given in my book ,

$|x+1| + |x-2| = |2x-1|$

$(x+1)(x+2) ≥ 0$

Hence , $x≤-1 , x≥2$

However I couldn’t understand the second step. How did they just factorise the equation that was in the modulus ? I initially thought of squaring but I believe that would be too long. So , what how can we solve such modulus equations by factorization ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we distinguish four cases:
1)$$x\geq 2$$ this is impossible
2)$$\frac{1}{2}\le x<2$$ then we have $$x+1-x+2=2x-1$$
3)$$-1\le x<\frac{1}{2}$$ we get $$x+1-x+2=-2x+1$$
4) $$x<-1$$ then we have $$-x-1-x+2=-2x+1$$

Comment: But $\;x\ge2\;$ is **not** impossible...in fact, it is part of the solution set. Also cases (2)-(3) are wrong as we don't get any solution there...

Answer (score 3):

By the triangle inequality
$$|2x-1|=|x+1|+|x-2|\geq|x+1+x-2|=|2x-1|.$$
The equality occurs, when $x+1$ and $x-2$ have  same sings, which gives the answer:
$$(-\infty,-1]\cup[2,+\infty).$$

Answer (score 2):

If you feel yourself lost you can always try cases:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet\;&x<-1&\implies& -(x+1)-(x-2)=-(2x-1)\implies1=1\implies \color{red}{x<-1}\\{}\\
\bullet\;&-1\le x<\frac12&\implies& (x+1)-(x-2)=-(2x-1)\implies3=-2x+1\implies \color{red}{x=-1}\\{}\\
\bullet\;&\frac12\le x<2&\implies&(x+1)-(x-2)=(2x-1)\implies 3=2x-1\implies x=2...\text{no solution}\\{}\\
\bullet\;&2\le x&\implies& (x+1)+(x-2)=(2x-1)\implies 0=0\implies \color{red}{x\ge2}\end{align*}$$

Thus **the** solution set is $\;\color{red}{(-\infty,-1]\cup[2,\infty)}\;$

Comment: Thank you for your help !